# How to use \tablefootnote package with \subcaption package

Tags: footnotes, subcaption

I want to use the package \tablefootnote because I want to put many footnotes in a table caption but footnotes appear twice:

[image]

I look where it comes from in my code and it seems that \tablefootnote is not compatible with \subcaption package because when I comment (%) this package everything works well:

[image]

I need \subcaption package to create subfigure.

Here is my simplify code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       A & B
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption \tablefootnote{footnote\_1}$^,$\tablefootnote{footnote\_2}.}
    \label{tab:A&D_eletromag}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to use these two packages simultaneously, is there a way to rectify this problem or is there a good alternative?

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the duplicate caused by `singlelinecheck`, you also need to remove the `\tablefootnote`s from the list of tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
       A & B
    \end{tabular}
    \captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false, justification=centering}
    \caption[Short caption]{Caption \tablefootnote{footnote\_1}$^,$\tablefootnote{footnote\_2}.}
    \label{tab:A&D_eletromag}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```